# How to Remove SQL Comments from sql queries stored in data frame?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sql-parser

I have data which is stored in dataframe with one of the column (query column) contains sql queries. I want to **remove all sql comments** from all these sql queries in data frame and retain the query column along with other columns in data frame.

Basically I want to modify existing data frame which contains query column. Although I know **sqlparse library** and implemented it on a single  cell element.

Using this:

```
print (sqlparse.format(data['Query'][0], strip_comments=True).strip())
```

It is applying only to one element, but I want to modify all the sql query values  in query column of that data frame.

Please note I also used loop concept to get removed all the sql comments from that query column using this below:

```
list=[]
for i in range(columns):
    list.append(sqlparse.format(data['Query'][i], strip_comments=True).strip())
c=pd.DataFrame(list)
```

This is working fine and I will get removed all the comments and get all query stored in this data frame c.

But the point is I want to modify in that **original data frame** so that I can use other columns (which has some other data stored) along with query column.

@ArchAngelPwn Sure.
Let say Data Frame df with column Name and SQL Query. As you see for each Name there is SQL Query with some comments. I want to remove such sql comments using python, so that data frame of sql query has  query only.

Name      SQL Query

A
SELECT * FROM sales

-- JOIN marketing on sales.id=marketing .Id

B
--SELECT * FROM C

SELECT * FROM Employee

C

SELECT * FROM

```
  Customer c

 JOIN Order o on c.id=o.id
```

/* This query give me data from
1 jan 2020 to 30 jan 2021 */

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data that is not a screenshot so we can look at your data directly?

Comment: I general I think you want to replace the old values with the new values (i.e., the original dataframe column is a list, and you replace those values with the new list - possibly something like `data['Query'].values = theNewList` but I am not sure if this is the correct syntax exactly).

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn Sure.
Let say Data Frame df with column Name and SQL Query. As you see for each Name there is SQL Query with some comments. I want to remove such sql comments using python, so that data frame of sql query has  query only.
Name  SQL Query
A)         SELECT * FROM A 
           -- JOIN B on A.id=B.Id

B)         --SELECT * FROM C
              SELECT * FROM Employee

C)          SELECT * FROM 
                   Customer c
                 JOIN Order o on c.id=o.id
             /* This query give me data from
                  1 jan 2020 to 30 jan 2021 */

Comment: data[''Query] = sqlparse.format(data['Query'], strip_comments=True).strip()) should do the trick